# 404 error on image handling asp.net mvc controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing

i have pretty annoying error that can;t figure out.

i have controller action that generates images. everything works ok on my development laptop win 7 pro iis 7.5.

but when i deploy it to win 2008 iis 7 images are not generated and i get 404 error.

can't imaging what wrong

thanks

Comment: Does the rest of the site work? Can you show us some of the code? Have you updated any referances?

Comment: rest of site work fine just without images.

public virtual void Picture()
{
   // writes image from db to response stream.
}
it works on iis 7.5. 

i assume it is configuration problem

Answer (score 1):

Check the file location of the images.

Are you using "~/Images/" or "../Images" ... this may be causing the code to look in the wrong spot for the images.

That always burns me when I move the project to the server.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL that you're using to access the action?  Does it end with a real file extension, such as jpg or png?

If so, you might be getting hit by IIS's static file handler.  Try accessing the controller/action via a different route, such as "image/generate/123".